# using while loop in which i want to enter stop to stop the loop

Tags: loops, while-loop

while True:
marks = int(input("Enter the marks: "))
print(marks)

```
if marks <= 40 :
    print("Grade F")

elif marks <= 50 :
    print("Grade E")
    
    
elif marks <= 70 :
    print("Grade D")
    
    
elif marks <= 80 :
    print("Grade C")
    
    
elif marks <= 90 :
    print("Grade B")
    
    
elif marks <= 100 :
    print("Grade A")
```

if marks == str.stop:
break

While trying to execute it shows me the below mentioned error:

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'stop'

Comment: Please tag your language as well

Comment: And the problem is that you convert any input to int - and "stop" is not a valid number. So first test the input for "stop" and then convert to int

Answer (score 0):

- This error because you are comparing an integer value `marks` to a string value `str.stop`
  so you need to make condition if the input is equal to "stop" the loop will be stopped using `break`

**This is the code for your question**

```
while True:
    marks = input("Enter the marks (or enter 'stop' to stop the loop): ")
    if marks == "stop":
        break

    marks = int(marks)
    print(marks)

    if marks <= 40:
        print("Grade F")
    elif marks <= 50:
        print("Grade E")
    elif marks <= 70:
        print("Grade D")
    elif marks <= 80:
        print("Grade C")
    elif marks <= 90:
        print("Grade B")
    elif marks <= 100:
        print("Grade A")
```

**Output**

```
Enter the marks (or enter 'stop' to stop the loop): 100
100
Grade A
Enter the marks (or enter 'stop' to stop the loop): 50
50
Grade E
Enter the marks (or enter 'stop' to stop the loop): 80
80
Grade C
Enter the marks (or enter 'stop' to stop the loop): stop
```